# Xcode Project read only solution

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

My Xcode project unfortunately changed to read only state, nothing is going to be modified. i cant able to forward. help me to change my Xcode status from read only to read/write.

help me to fix it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware with this problem but this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559542/how-to-unlock-xcode-file-to-make-edits-from-different-computers/9561906#9561906

Comment: i tried it but not solved

Comment: Some possible solutions: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235577/cant-save-any-files-in-xcode-due-to-permission-error), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051228/xcode-the-document-could-not-be-saved-you-don-t-have-permission) and [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2300074).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the Terminal and change it:

```
cd PATH #where PATH is the directory where you project is
sudo chown -R YOURUSER:staff .
sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

Thant will reset all permission to writable for you, readonly for others